# Spring Java app not finding the keystore file

Tags: java, linux, spring, ssl, tomcat

I am trying to set up a simple Spring application to use SSL and host it on Digital Ocean. Why is my app not finding the keystore file?

The droplet I've set up is based on Ubuntu 18.04. I used Letsencrypt to get a certificate and [this](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-secured-by-lets-encrypt) guide to generate a PKCS file. I've set up my application.properties file to look in the jar file's current directory like so:

```
security.require-ssl:true
server.ssl.key-store:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password:<password>
server.ssl.key-store-type:PKCS12
server.ssl.key-alias:<alias>
```

I would expect this to run and start a web server on the configured port. However, what I get in the stack trace is this:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/software/gimmememe/target/keystore.p12  (No such file or directory)
```

Weirdly enough when I run the same jar with the same keystore.p12 file on my own Windows machine it runs fine:

```
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9123 (https) with context path ''
meme.Application                         : Started Application in 4.985 seconds (JVM running for 5.464)
```

I don't think it's a permissions issue on the Ubuntu machine as I tried setting the permissions on the keystore file like so:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     4274 Mar 26 18:44 keystore.p12
```

I am running my jar file with the following command (tried with sudo infront as well):

```
java -jar gimme-meme-1.0.0.war
```

Comment: Your tomcat is running as root? In the target directory.

Comment: I am only using the embedded tomcat within Spring. I am not sure if that's exactly how it works but I'm just running the jar from the command line. Also I will not be running as root when this is all set up.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'the JAR file's curremt directory'. There is the current working directory, and the directory where the JAR file is located, and they aren't necessarily the same thing, especially in a WEB container.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion then. I mean the directory where the JAR is located and that's where I also place the keystore.p12 file

Comment: So then you have to name it completely, because that's not where the container is looking. You only provided the filename, so it looks in *its* current working directory, and you can see what that is from the error message. So, err, put it *there*.

Comment: It is indeed there. That's what is so confusing about this whole thing.

Comment: As suggested by @isapir there was a trailing space character in the filename. Not exactly sure how it got there and why Spring does not clean it automatically. For some reason this wasn't an issue when running in Windows... Anyway that solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring loads the file from the classpath, which allows, so you should prefix the path with that `classpath:`, e.g.

```
server.ssl.key-store : classpath:keystore.p12
```

Or if you use the `=` symbol as a key/value delimiter:

```
server.ssl.key-store = classpath:keystore.p12
```

Bear in mind that the value is only trimmed on the left side, so you can not have any trailing whitespace after the value.

Comment: It appears that on the Ubuntu machine Spring was not cleaning trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same issues and could resolve it.
I stored the keystore file in *src/main/resources/keystore.p12*, but in the jar file it was under *classes/* directly.
My solution was:

```
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your app is just looking in the current directory for the keystore.p12 file, as indicated by:

`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/software/gimmememe/target/keystore.p12  (No such file or directory)`

Most likely, you need to tell Spring Boot that the file is *in* the jar.

For example, if you keep the file at `src/main/resources`, gradle & maven will place that file at the root of the classpath.  To convey this information to the spring boot app, you'll want to tell it the file is on the classpath.

That means you need to set `server.ssl.key-store` to `classpath:keystore.p12`, so that Spring knows it needs to load the keystore from within the archive's classpath.

-- EDIT --

Here's an example of someone having a similar problem that illustrates this fix.

[Github Issue of Similar Problem](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9089)

Comment: 'In the JAR file's current directory' does not mean 'in the JAR file'.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried putting the keystore.p12 file in ```src/main/resources``` and it is indeed included in the output jar. I added ```classpath:``` in front of the file name too and I got the following error:

```FileNotFoundException: class path resource [keystore.p12 ] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```
I believe this has to be an environment issue given that it runs fine on my Windows machine.

Comment: @MZokov, if you try running the same `java -jar` command from your windows machine, with the file in the jar, does it work? If we can get that to work, then it should port to wherever you deploy the application.

Another option is to just copy the .p12 file to wherever you are deploying the app and place it right next to the running jar.  I personally prefer bundling it in so that the jar is portable and can work anywhere.

Comment: Also, if you're running the project as a `war`, `src/main/resources` might not actually end up on the root of the classpath - you might need to put it at `src/main/resources/WEB-INF`, I'm not sure if it needs to be further nested, but wars are treated differently than pure spring boot jars.

Comment: I am actually getting the same error on my Windows machine. ```FileNotFoundException: class path resource [keystore.p12 ] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist``` . I will try a regular jar instead of a war as well. I'm not sure I need it to necessarily be a war.

Comment: Building as a jar and running with ```server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12``` gives me the following (slightly different) result: ```.WebServerException: Could not load key store: class path resource [keystore.p12 ] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist``` on both the Windows and Ubuntu machines.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you changed it back to a jar you're placing the keystore in `src/main/resources` still? Also, you might need to make sure that you are using the spring boot plugin to make an uber jar, so you should be able to find that .p12 file in the jar, in the `BOOT-INF` folder I believe?