# Unable to start embedded tomcat server when maven project build success

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I'm making my own project using maven, spring-boot.
When i build my project, compiler said build success.
then, run application, it always said "Unable to start embedded tomcat server". I don't know why this error happend. i thought when build is success, run application is work. but i'm wrong. what is problem in my code?
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.fkwg.hackathon</groupId>
    <artifactId>fido2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>fido2</name>
    <description>fido2 hackathon</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

success message

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< com.fkwg.hackathon:fido2 >----------------------
[INFO] Building fido2 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ fido2 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 12 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ fido2 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ fido2 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/junbeomkwak/Downloads/fido486-rp/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ fido2 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) @ fido2 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.fkwg.hackathon.fido2.Fido2ApplicationTests
22:57:45.282 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
22:57:45.309 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
22:57:45.374 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [com.fkwg.hackathon.fido2.Fido2ApplicationTests] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper]
22:57:45.399 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.fkwg.hackathon.fido2.Fido2ApplicationTests], using SpringBootContextLoader
22:57:45.409 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.fkwg.hackathon.fido2.Fido2ApplicationTests]: class path resource [com/fkwg/hackathon/fido2/Fido2ApplicationTests-context.xml] does not exist
22:57:45.412 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.fkwg.hackathon.fido2.Fido2ApplicationTests]: class path resource [com/fkwg/hackathon/fido2/Fido2ApplicationTestsContext.groovy] does not exist
22:57:45.412 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.fkwg.hackathon.fido2.Fido2ApplicationTests]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
22:57:45.414 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.fkwg.hackathon.fido2.Fido2ApplicationTests]: Fido2ApplicationTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
22:57:45.463 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.fkwg.hackathon.fido2.Fido2ApplicationTests]
22:57:45.551 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [/Users/junbeomkwak/Downloads/fido486-rp/target/classes/com/fkwg/hackathon/fido2/Fido2Application.class]
22:57:45.553 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration com.fkwg.hackathon.fido2.Fido2Application for test class com.fkwg.hackathon.fido2.Fido2ApplicationTests
22:57:45.668 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [com.fkwg.hackathon.fido2.Fido2ApplicationTests]: using defaults.
22:57:45.669 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener]
22:57:45.703 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@55cf0d14, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@3b74ac8, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@27adc16e, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@b83a9be, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@2609b277, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@1fd14d74, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@563e4951, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@4066c471, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@2b175c00, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@3eb81efb, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@1ae8bcbc, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@6cdba6dc, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@7d3d101b]
22:57:45.712 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@327af41b testClass = Fido2ApplicationTests, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@6cb6decd testClass = Fido2ApplicationTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.fkwg.hackathon.fido2.Fido2Application}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@13b13b5d, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@29647f75, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@73ee04c8, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@625732], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
22:57:45.743 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils - Adding inlined properties to environment: {spring.jmx.enabled=false, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true, server.port=-1}

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.4.RELEASE)

[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.782 s - in com.fkwg.hackathon.fido2.Fido2ApplicationTests
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.1.2:jar (default-jar) @ fido2 ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/junbeomkwak/Downloads/fido486-rp/target/fido2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.4.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) @ fido2 ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ fido2 ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/junbeomkwak/Downloads/fido486-rp/target/fido2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/junbeomkwak/.m2/repository/com/fkwg/hackathon/fido2/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/fido2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/junbeomkwak/Downloads/fido486-rp/pom.xml to /Users/junbeomkwak/.m2/repository/com/fkwg/hackathon/fido2/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/fido2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  14.911 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-07-25T22:57:55+09:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53620', transport: 'socket'
```

and when i execute fido2.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, this error message happend.

```
2020-07-25 23:01:06.066 ERROR 4142 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:297) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.fkwg.hackathon.fido2.Fido2Application.main(Fido2Application.java:11) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[fido2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[fido2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) ~[fido2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) ~[fido2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:278) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1008) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /Users/junbeomkwak/Downloads/fido486-rp/target/keystore.p12 (No such file or directory)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:217) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:586) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1005) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/junbeomkwak/Downloads/fido486-rp/target/keystore.p12 (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:212) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:154) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:109) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:184) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.CatalinaBaseConfigurationSource.getResource(CatalinaBaseConfigurationSource.java:116) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:283) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

then, when i move keystore.p12 file, then keystore.p12 error is gone. but some error still happend.

```
2020-07-25 23:23:12.702 ERROR 4997 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:297) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.fkwg.hackathon.fido2.Fido2Application.main(Fido2Application.java:11) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[fido2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[fido2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) ~[fido2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) ~[fido2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:278) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1008) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:217) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:586) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1005) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:328) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoi
```

i edited my application.properties, and look my p12 file. then when i execute /target/.jar file, process just stop..
application.properties

```
logging.level.root=error
#server.ssl.key-store=cert_key.p12
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store-password=wnsqja0380
server.ssl.key-alias=1
server.port = 8080
```

and keystore.p12

```
Alias name: 1
Creation date: 2020. 7. 23.
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 2
Certificate[1]:
```

and when i execuce /target/.jar file. just stop like this

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.4.RELEASE)
```

Comment: As per the stack trace: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /Users/junbeomkwak/Downloads/fido486-rp/target/keystore.p12 (No such file or directory)
Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364537/spring-java-app-not-finding-the-keystore-file

Comment: @harry i did what you said. so i copied keystore.p12 file to target folder and give chmod 777 permisson. so the keystore.p12 error is gone. but some error still happend. i will update another error at my post.

Comment: @harry i update another error

Comment: Now the issue with entry **jsse.alias_no_key_entry** in the Keystore. Try to list down all the available attributes in the Keystore for more information.

Comment: Try this `keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.p12 -storepass <password>` to list the entries and then you can check whether that alias is there or not.

Comment: Asper the error you need to add alish while creating your .p12 certificate

Comment: @harry alias is 1. i will update my post. i edit my application.properties, and rebuild and execute /target/.jar file. but it just stop... what happend?

Comment: update my post.

Comment: Is it possible that you have more than 1 java/jre?